# C++ Undefined reference to a function

Tags: compiling, c++, g++

I am using ubuntu 16.04 When I try to compile the program with

```
g++ -g main.cpp -o main
```

This is my g++ version

```
g++ --version
```

```
g++ (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I get this compilation error

```
main.cpp:8: undefined reference to `Helper::IsStringNumeric(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "Helper.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


int main()
{
    std::cout << Helper::IsStringNumeric("200");
}
```

Helper.h

```
#ifndef HELPER_H
#define HELPER_H

#include <vector>
#include <string>
class Helper
{
private:
    /* data */
public:
    
   static bool IsStringNumeric(const std::string &str);
   
};

#endif
```

Helper.cpp

```
#include "Helper.h"
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
bool Helper::IsStringNumeric(const std::string &str)
{
    std::string::const_iterator iterator = str.begin();
    
    while (iterator != str.end() && std::isdigit(*iterator))
    {
        ++iterator;
    }
    return !str.empty() && iterator == str.end();
}
```

My cpp and header files seem right , So I am not sure why I am getting errors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding `#include "Helper.h"` to your `main.cpp` makes the *declaration* of `Helper::IsStringNumeric` visible to the compiler, but you still need to compile `Helper.cpp` to object code in order to make the *definition* of `Helper::IsStringNumeric` available when you link your `main` program.

You can either compile each translation unit to an object code *file* and then link them:

```
g++ -g -o main.o -c main.cpp
g++ -g -o Helper.o -c Helper.cpp
g++ main.o Helper.o -o main
```

or (for simple programs) do it all in one step

```
g++ -g main.cpp Helper.cpp -o main
```